# Custom source property for VideoOutput QML

Tags: c++, qt, video, qtquick2, qtmultimedia

What exactly has to be done to provide custom source of frames for `VideoOutput` QML object?

Does `VideoOuput` itself provide an instance of  `QAbstractVideoSurface` class to the "source"?

The Qt5 documentations says following thing about providing about this issue:

> If you are extending your own C++ classes to interoperate with
>   VideoOutput, you can either provide a QObject based class with a
>   mediaObject property that exposes a QMediaObject derived class that
>   has a QVideoRendererControl available, or you can provide a QObject
>   based class with a writable videoSurface property that can accept a
>   QAbstractVideoSurface based class and can follow the correct protocol
>   to deliver QVideoFrames to it.

In accordance to following documentation I did the following:

1. I implmented my own class `myFrameProvider` derived from `QObject` that has writable `videoSurface` property.
2. Make a class connected to the following that sends frames to myFrameProvider.
3. Instantianted `myFrameProvider` class and made it accessible in the same QML context as `VideoOutput' widget.

After that - I'm getting the segfault whenever "videSurface" property is accessed.
Should I set my own video surface property??

Answer (score 13):

While having a similar problem, I stumbled across your question. A bit after, I found a solution, which worked for me. Even if your question is an older one and you probably moved on, I want to share my answer to potentially help other people.

I found the answer in the [QT documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videooverview.html) in the section "Working with Low Level Video Frames". The piece of code posted there, was very helpful as starting point, but I had to modify it, so that it woks properly. A minimal working example looks like this:

**FrameProvider.h**

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractVideoSurface>
#include <QVideoSurfaceFormat>

class FameProvider : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QAbstractVideoSurface *videoSurface READ videoSurface WRITE setVideoSurface)


public:
    QAbstractVideoSurface* videoSurface() const { return m_surface; }

private:
    QAbstractVideoSurface *m_surface = NULL;
    QVideoSurfaceFormat m_format;

public:


    void setVideoSurface(QAbstractVideoSurface *surface)
    {
        if (m_surface && m_surface != surface  && m_surface->isActive()) {
            m_surface->stop();
        }

        m_surface = surface;

        if (m_surface && m_format.isValid())
        {
            m_format = m_surface->nearestFormat(m_format);
            m_surface->start(m_format);

        }
    }

    void setFormat(int width, int heigth, int format)
    {
        QSize size(width, heigth);
        QVideoSurfaceFormat format(size, format);
        m_format = format;

        if (m_surface) 
        {
            if (m_surface->isActive())
            {
                m_surface->stop();
            }
            m_format = m_surface->nearestFormat(m_format);
            m_surface->start(m_format);
        }
    }

public slots:
    void onNewVideoContentReceived(const QVideoFrame &frame)
    {

        if (m_surface)
            m_surface->present(frame);
    }
};
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.2
import QtMultimedia 5.4
import com.yourcompany.FrameProvider 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    objectName: "mainWindow"
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    FrameProvider{
        objectName: "provider"
        id: provider
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: display
        objectName: "display"
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        width: parent.width
        source: provider
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // initialize the qml application engine
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    //register the custom control to the qml application engine
    qmlRegisterType<FameProvider>("com.yourcompany.FrameProvider", 1, 0, "FrameProvider");

    // start the view
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
    {
    return -1;
    }

    // find your custom control
    QObject *rootObject = engine.rootObjects().first();
    Qobject *display = rootObject->findChild<QObject *>("display");
    auto provider = qvariant_cast<FameProvider *>(display->property("source"));

    // Create your custom frame source class, which inherits from QObject. This source is expected to have the following public fields and signals:
    // - int width
    // - int height
    // - int format (following QVideoFrame::PixelFormat)
    // - signals: void newFrameAvailable(const QVideoFrame &frame);
    CustomFramesource source;

    // Set the correct format for the video surface (Make sure your selected format is supported by the surface)
    provider->setFormat(source.width,source.height, source.format);

    // Connect your frame source with the provider
    QObject::connect(&source, SIGNAL(newFrameAvailable(const QVideoFrame &)), provider, SLOT(onNewVideoContentReceived(const QVideoFrame &)));

    // run the app
    int retVal =  app.exec();

    return 0;
}
```

The MWE is condensed from my actual code and thus untested. I hope it runs anyway and shows all needed steps.

Comment: A key part to this answer is to supply something to the `m_format` member as given in the [Qt video document](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/videooverview.html).  You can also set this statically in the constructor; but you need the supplied format to match the [video surface supported types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractvideosurface.html#supportedPixelFormats).  As an aside, the QVideoFrame `startTime` and `endTime` don't seem to be used for anything and it is not clear what the absolute time base is.