# MediaPlayer in QtQuick play video that each frame stored in memory

Tags: video, qml

The source of MediaPlayer in all official tutorials are files,just like this:

```
 MediaPlayer{
     id:player
     source:fileFullPath // local or remote file path
     autoPlay: true
     volume: voice.value
 }
 VideoOutput {
     anchors.fill: parent
     source: player
 }
```

But if my videos are restored in memory,how can i set the property "source"?

Comment: What do you mean saying `in memory`? A file? Some structure? How do you access the data now?

Comment: "memory" just means heap space i allocated from OS. In fact,i received streaming media from internet,and each frame was stored in "memory". I want show the  frame when i received it immediately.

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43854589/custom-source-property-for-videooutput-qml) similar question could be useful for you.